# Непонятен синтаксис. Что реализует данный фрагмент кода: "(...nums: List[int]) -> int"

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

```py
class Solution:   
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
```

Comment: Подсказка: используйте не `'` (апостроф), а `\`` для оформления кода

Comment: Это аннотация типов в питоне. На хабре не плохо описано https://habr.com/ru/company/lamoda/blog/432656/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
```

1. Объявление класса `Solution` с методом `removeDuplicates`. То, что это метод, это из-за первого параметра `self`
2. В методе описывается, что он принимает параметр `nums` и его тип -- список целых чисел (`List[int]`), и метод возвращает целое число (`-> int:`)